# Views 2d and 3d model in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Help me with my model in Anylogic. For example, when launching the model, there should be a button for switching between 2d and 3d views. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a 3D window to your canvas. You can find this in the presentation palette, in the 3D section... (the last element of the following image):
[image: 3d window]

You can put the 3D window anywhere, then when you run the simulation you can click on the view icon and select window3D

[image: view icon]

This is a simplified answer because the reality is that you should use the camera to visualize what you want to visualize... But this is the most basic way to get a 3D view

Comment: I know, but I need to put the button on the model when pushed to which 2D will change on 3D and vice versa

Comment: check out my blog post on view areas and how to jump between different areas of your AnyLogic model: http://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/3/28/anylogic-user-interface-vol-4-the-view-area